# Does Visual Studio 2010 have tooling support for IronRuby?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2010, ironruby

I am interested in the following features: Code highlighting, Intellisense, Refactorings, Code navigation (Go to Definition etc.).

If this functionality is missing from Visual Studio 2010 maybe Microsoft is planning to add these features in the future or there are community project to develop IronRuby tooling add-in?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371569/ironruby-ide which seems to cover the same ground.

Comment: I've read it, but all answers in that thread are 8+ months old. I am pretty sure something have changed since that post. Visual Studio 2010 released recently and I am interested in its IronRuby support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has recently released [IronPython tools for Visual Studio](http://ironpython.net/tools/) and they are working on the same thing for IronRuby. 
No planned release date yet but they are working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Good news! IronRuby Tools for Visual Studio 2010 were released on 21 OCT 2010 and are available here: http://ironruby.codeplex.com/releases/view/49097

Comment: Unfortunately as of 2013-04-01 the tools don't appear to have VS2012 support:
http://ironruby.codeplex.com/workitem/7345

Answer (score 0):

no native support. [not by microsoft directly](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/479957/ironruby-integration-in-visual-studio-2010)

[Ruby in Steel](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1564484&seqNum=4)

This add-on to Visual Studio by SapphireSteel makes developing Ruby applications inside Visual Studio much more natural. It adds new Ruby project types, intellisense, code snippets, and syntax highlighting. But it costs money.

Comment: The OP asked about VS support for IronRuby. Ruby in Steel supports pretty much every Ruby implementation (MRI, YARV and JRuby) *except* IronRuby.

Comment: why don't you read the link to the article I sent? >> Although you cannot run IronRuby with Ruby in Steel out of the box, it is possible to alter the solution settings to execute ir.exe. Follow these steps to do so ... better support you wont get. The yrticle was written by the author of the IronRuby book ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, SapphireSteel Software released a free IronRuby IDE way back in February 2008 - with code coloring, project management, build and run, visual form design etc. However, the IronRuby team was not overwhelmingly supportive of this project and we have now ceased development as explained here: http://www.sapphiresteel.com/Goodbye-IronRuby-Hello-Ruby-In

best wishes

Huw Collingbourne

SapphireSteel Software